# dict.update() выдает ответ, который я не могу объяснить

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

```
fmtText = "Lorem ipsum dolor! diam amet, consetetur Lorem magna. sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor. diam et labore? et diam magna. et diam amet."

freqMap = {}
wordList = fmtText.split(' ')
for word in set(wordList):
    freqMap.update({word:fmtText.count(word)}) 
print(freqMap)
```

> {'amet.': 1, 'nonumy': 1, 'consetetur': 1, 'magna.': 2, 'diam': 5, 'sed': 1, 'labore?': 1, 'dolor!': 1, 'tempor.': 1, 'Lorem': 2, 'eirmod': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'et': 7}

```
fmtText = "Lorem ipsum dolor! diam amet, consetetur Lorem magna. sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor. diam et labore? et diam magna. et diam amet."
# split text into words
wordList = fmtText.split(' ')
# Create dictionary
freqMap = {}

for word in set(wordList): # use set to remove duplicates in list
            freqMap[word] = wordList.count(word)
print(freqMap)
```

> {'amet.': 1, 'nonumy': 1, 'consetetur': 1, 'magna.': 2, 'diam': 5, 'sed': 1, 'labore?': 1, 'dolor!': 1, 'tempor.': 1, 'Lorem': 2, 'eirmod': 1, 'amet,': 1, 'ipsum': 1, 'et': 3}

Не могу понять, почему et  = 3, в первом случае, а во втором et = 7 (второе это к-во et  во всем тексте, а в первом слов et)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в `dict.update`, а в используемом способе подсчета.

В первом случае вы считаете не по списку слов, а по строке (`fmtText.count(word)` вместо `wordList.count(word)`), поэтому "et" считается просто как сочетание букв, в том числе в составе других слов, например в словах am**et**, cons**etet**ur и т.д.

Вообще, для подсчета одинаковых объектов удобно использовать Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

fmtText = ...
freqMap = Counter(fmtText.split(' '))
print(dict(freqMap))
# Преобразовывать в dict не обязательно,
# добавил чтобы вывод был аналогичный выводу кода в вопросе
```

Comment: Ай карамба, спасибо!